# VBA: For each loop, copy if data is between dates

Tags: vba, loops, date, for-loop

I'm trying to get my Excel sheet to automatically copy data, if a specific date is between two predefined dates.

Unfortunately my "For" loop seems to copy the last match it finds, not the first few.

My code is as follows:

```
'Check if sold between declared dates
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim tempDate As Date
    Dim oldDate As Date
    Dim lateDate As Date
    Dim startDate
    Dim endDate
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAV")
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
    Worksheets("SETTINGS").Activate
    Set startDate = Range("D10")
    Set endDate = Range("D12")
    
    If IsDate(startDate.Value) Then
    If IsDate(endDate.Value) Then
        oldDate = startDate.Value
        lateDate = endDate.Value
    End If
    End If
    
    For Each cell In sh.Range("C2:C" & sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
            If cell >= oldDate And cell <= lateDate Then
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
            End If
    Next cell
```

Which just results in 1 line being copied to the CALCULATION tab, even though there's more matches.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont update the `LastRow` variable it remains the same.
Update it in the for loop after the `cell.EntireRow.Copy`.
Would be:

```
    For Each cell In sh.Range("C2:C" & sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
        If cell >= oldDate And cell <= lateDate Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy 
            Destination:=Worksheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CALCULATIONS").Range("A" & 
            Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        End If
Next cell
```